# Difficult matching of array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this array:

```
@array = [["1003", "4"], ["963", "3"], ["1006", "1"], ["1064", "1"], ["1095", "1"], ["963", "http://www.google.com/1"], ["1003", "http://www.google.com/2"]]
```

and i need this as result:

```
@array = [["1003", "http://www.google.com/2"], ["963", "http://www.google.com/1"]]
```

1. Matching every [0] with each other, if it fits set "http: link" to [1].
2. Delete all entrys with no matching.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Hash[@array].reject{|k,v| v == "1"}.to_a
```

What this is doing:

Initialize array:

```
@array => [["1003", "4"], ["963", "3"], ["1006", "1"], ["1064", "1"], ["1095", "1"], ["963", "http://www.google.com/1"], ["1003", "http://www.google.com/2"]]
```

Convert to hash:

```
hash = Hash[@array] => {"1003"=>"http://www.google.com/2", "963"=>"http://www.google.com/1", "1006"=>"1", "1064"=>"1", "1095"=>"1"}
```

Remove where the value is == "1":

```
hash = hash.reject!{|k,v| v == "1"} => {"1003"=>"http://www.google.com/2", "963"=>"http://www.google.com/1"}
```

Convert back to array:

```
hash.to_a => [["1003", "http://www.google.com/2"], ["963", "http://www.google.com/1"]]
```

reject is an alias of [delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if)

Comment: you need a `to_a` on the end to match the OP's output.

Comment: With an additional `to_a` at the end so it's in the array format OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

magic!

```
@array = [["1003", "4"], ["963", "3"], ["1006", "1"], ["1064", "1"], ["1095", "1"], ["963", "http://www.google.com/1"], ["1003", "http://www.google.com/2"]] 

@links = @array.select { |item| item[1].match(/http/)}
@non_links = @array - @links
@non_links.map do |non_link|
  if @links.map(&:first).include? non_link.first
    [non_link.first, @links.select { |link| link.first == non_link.first }.first.last]
  end
end.compact
```

Comment: Thx, this "@links = @array.select { |item| item[1].match(/http/)}
" was extremly helpful for me!!

Comment: No problems. You could combine that with the top ander and use something like `Hash[@array].select{|k,v| v.match(/http/)}.to_a` should work :)